# What could be causing the crash in my game?

Tags: xamarin, crash, segmentation-fault, urhosharp

I've created a game using UrhoSharp on Xamarin. It seems fine when testing it on the simulator, but when I tried to test it on a device it keeps crashing.

Crash report:

[image]

Crash report transcript:

```
2019-06-11 12:08:07.402 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical: Stacktrace:

2019-06-11 12:08:07.402 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
2019-06-11 12:08:07.403 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <0x00007>
2019-06-11 12:08:07.403 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],intptr,intptr) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
2019-06-11 12:08:07.403 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0002c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
2019-06-11 12:08:07.404 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   at draw.iOS.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00001] in /Users/developer/Desktop/draw1/draw/draw/draw.iOS/Main.cs:17
2019-06-11 12:08:07.404 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_dynamic (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0001e] in <2b439461a53d406abf16d6e5e34ece7f#FC3AB111-7950-164E-E247-31CDD1528289>:0
2019-06-11 12:08:07.404 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical: 
Native stacktrace:

2019-06-11 12:08:07.411 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   0   draw.iOS                            0x000000010370fe98 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 45682360
2019-06-11 12:08:07.412 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   1   draw.iOS                            0x000000010371db68 mono_pmip + 16100
2019-06-11 12:08:07.412 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x000000018356bb60 _sigtramp + 52
2019-06-11 12:08:07.412 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   3   AGXGLDriver                         0x00000001a292a238 gldUpdateDispatch + 7296
2019-06-11 12:08:07.412 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   4   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib          0x000000019e989edc gpusSubmitDataBuffers + 176
2019-06-11 12:08:07.413 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   5   AGXGLDriver                         0x00000001a292b734 gldUpdateDispatch + 12668
2019-06-11 12:08:07.413 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   6   GLEngine                            0x00000001a391b01c <redacted> + 188
2019-06-11 12:08:07.413 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   7   OpenGLES                            0x00000001867dda8c <redacted> + 80
2019-06-11 12:08:07.413 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   8   Urho                                0x000000010454534c UIKit_GL_RestoreCurrentContext + 2708
2019-06-11 12:08:07.413 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   9   Urho                                0x00000001045444b8 UIKit_GL_SwapWindow + 84
2019-06-11 12:08:07.414 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   10  Urho                                0x00000001041e4a94 _ZN6Urho3D8Graphics8EndFrameEv + 136
2019-06-11 12:08:07.414 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   11  Urho                                0x0000000104177c38 _ZN6Urho3D6Engine6RenderEv + 172
2019-06-11 12:08:07.414 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   12  Urho                                0x00000001041779a8 _ZN6Urho3D6Engine8RunFrameEv + 252
2019-06-11 12:08:07.414 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   13  QuartzCore                          0x000000018780efd4 <redacted> + 672
2019-06-11 12:08:07.414 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   14  IOKit                               0x0000000183bae30c IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 392
2019-06-11 12:08:07.414 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001838d2080 <redacted> + 188
2019-06-11 12:08:07.415 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001838ec9dc <redacted> + 56
2019-06-11 12:08:07.415 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001838ec0e0 <redacted> + 440
2019-06-11 12:08:07.415 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001838e9bb4 <redacted> + 2196
2019-06-11 12:08:07.415 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018380a2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
2019-06-11 12:08:07.415 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   20  Urho                                0x0000000104542f00 UIKit_PumpEvents + 64
2019-06-11 12:08:07.416 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   21  Urho                                0x00000001044fa654 SDL_PollEvent + 32
2019-06-11 12:08:07.416 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   22  Urho                                0x00000001042765f8 _ZN6Urho3D5Input6UpdateEv + 196
2019-06-11 12:08:07.416 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   23  Urho                                0x000000010427f97c _ZN6Urho3D5Input16HandleBeginFrameENS_10StringHashERNS_7HashMapIS1_NS_7VariantEEE + 52
2019-06-11 12:08:07.416 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   24  Urho                                0x0000000104137ac0 _ZN6Urho3D5Audio9MixOutputEPvj + 1340
2019-06-11 12:08:07.416 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   25  Urho                                0x000000010415bef4 _ZN6Urho3D6Object7OnEventEPS0_NS_10StringHashERNS_7HashMapIS2_NS_7VariantEEE + 140
2019-06-11 12:08:07.416 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   26  Urho                                0x000000010415d090 _ZN6Urho3D6Object9SendEventENS_10StringHashERNS_7HashMapIS1_NS_7VariantEEE + 920
2019-06-11 12:08:07.417 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   27  Urho                                0x0000000104165038 _ZN6Urho3D4Time10BeginFrameEf + 280
2019-06-11 12:08:07.417 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   28  Urho                                0x0000000104177954 _ZN6Urho3D6Engine8RunFrameEv + 168
2019-06-11 12:08:07.417 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   29  QuartzCore                          0x000000018780efd4 <redacted> + 672
2019-06-11 12:08:07.417 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   30  IOKit                               0x0000000183bae30c IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 392
2019-06-11 12:08:07.417 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   31  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001838d2080 <redacted> + 188
2019-06-11 12:08:07.418 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   32  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001838ec9dc <redacted> + 56
2019-06-11 12:08:07.418 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   33  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001838ec0e0 <redacted> + 440
2019-06-11 12:08:07.418 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   34  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001838e9bb4 <redacted> + 2196
2019-06-11 12:08:07.419 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   35  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018380a2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
2019-06-11 12:08:07.419 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   36  GraphicsServices                    0x000000018569bf84 GSEventRunModal + 100
2019-06-11 12:08:07.419 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   37  UIKit                               0x000000018cdb7880 UIApplicationMain + 208
2019-06-11 12:08:07.419 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   38  draw.iOS                            0x0000000101af5eb8 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 16215768
2019-06-11 12:08:07.420 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   39  draw.iOS                            0x0000000101a67d7c _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 15633820
2019-06-11 12:08:07.420 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   40  draw.iOS                            0x0000000101a67d3c _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 15633756
2019-06-11 12:08:07.420 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   41  draw.iOS                            0x0000000100be1550 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 402800
2019-06-11 12:08:07.420 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   42  draw.iOS                            0x0000000100edd228 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 3531336
2019-06-11 12:08:07.420 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   43  draw.iOS                            0x0000000103720d34 mono_pmip + 28848
2019-06-11 12:08:07.420 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   44  draw.iOS                            0x00000001037a4db8 mono_pmip + 569652
2019-06-11 12:08:07.421 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   45  draw.iOS                            0x00000001037aac9c mono_pmip + 593944
2019-06-11 12:08:07.421 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   46  draw.iOS                            0x000000010370120c _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 45621804
2019-06-11 12:08:07.421 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   47  draw.iOS                            0x0000000103898df8 _Z9__isctypeim + 55632
2019-06-11 12:08:07.421 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   48  draw.iOS                            0x0000000100be1450 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 402544
2019-06-11 12:08:07.421 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical:   49  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000018332e56c <redacted> + 4
2019-06-11 12:08:07.422 draw.iOS[350:38933] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```